# How to subset and print the table using the WHILE loop in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, group-by, subset

```
DECLARE @DATA_COL INT = 1
DECLARE @DATA_New INT
DECLARE @Total_COLUMN INT
DECLARE @Trial NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Column INT
DECLARE @plot INT
DECLARE @trt INT
DECLARE @rep INT
DECLARE @block INT
DECLARE @data INT

SET @Total_COLUMN = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (DATA_COLUMN)) FROM FINAL_DATA 
                     WHERE FINAL_DATA.TRIAL_ID='AU_1')
SET @DATA_COL = 1

WHILE @DATA_COL <= @Total_COLUMN
BEGIN 
    PRINT (SELECT 
               @Trial = TRIAL_ID, @Column=DATA_COLUMN, @plot = PLOT_NO, 
               @trt = TRT_NO, @rep = REP_NO, @block = BLOCK_NO, @data = DATA 
           FROM 
               FINAL_DATA 
           WHERE 
               FINAL_DATA.TRIAL_ID = 'AU_1' AND DATA_COLUMN = @DATA_COL)

    SET @DATA_COL = @DATA_COL + 1
END
```

I am trying to subset the table with the distinct DATA_COLUMN value. I am not able to print the query.

I get this error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me to solve the problem.

I have also tried another approach.

```
select
    TRIAL_ID, DATA_COLUMN, PLOT_NO, TRT_NO, REP_NO, BLOCK_NO,DATA
from
    FINAL_DATA
group by
    DATA_COLUMN, TRIAL_ID
```

Running this code, I get this error:

> Column 'FINAL_DATA.PLOT_NO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That code is product specific.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT DATA_COLUMN)` to make code clearer.

Comment: I need to create several subsets of data out of the table with the specific column value. If I put the count in it then it will only give the total number of data. That is why I didn't write count on it. Can you please guide me to subset the table?

Comment: I am using a relational DBMS i.e. SQL.

Comment: There are so many different DBMS databases supporting the SQL language. Perhaps you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, I am using MS SQL Server.